# How to sum attributes grouped by some predicate

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have many nodes and relationships of this form:

`(e:Employee)-[r:charged_project { hours: 10 }]->(p:Project { name : "Foo")`

How can I formulate a query that will give me a list of all projects, along with the total number of hours charged against them? (That is, the sum of all "hours" properties on inbound :charged_project relationships)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `sum` function to aggregate over the set of results and calculate the sum of hours:

```
MATCH (p:Project)<-[r:charged_project]-() RETURN p.name, sum (r.hours)
```

Comment: So the aggregation by project happens...how here?

Comment: `sum` is an aggregate function. The other return expression, `p.name` is not, so it will be used to group results. Think of an implicit `GROUP BY` by all expressions which are not aggregate functions.